# Issue with wso2 GREG 4.5.0 and postgresql as external DB

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I configured the GReg 4.5.0 to use an external DB in postgresql.
When I run wso2server.bat -Dsetup I see this error:

```
    TID: [-1234] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-10-17 23:35:38,514] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer} -  Humantask Database Initialization failed. {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer}
    TID: [-1234] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-10-17 23:35:38,527] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Failed to activate the HumanTaskServiceComponent. {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent}
    org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskServerException: Humantask Database Initialization failed.
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer.initDataSource(HumanTaskServer.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer.init(HumanTaskServer.java:95)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent.initHumanTaskServer(HumanTaskServiceComponent.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent.activate(HumanTaskServiceComponent.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
.... 
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskServerException: Error creating HumanTask database
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database.setupHumanTaskDatabase(Database.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database.start(Database.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer.initDataSource(HumanTaskServer.java:165)
        ... 131 more
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing SQL script for creating registry database
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQLScript(DatabaseCreator.java:333)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database.setupHumanTaskDatabase(Database.java:94)
        ... 133 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Jorge\DESARR~1\GREG\WSO2GR~1.0\bin\..\dbscripts\bps\postgresql.sql (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQLScript(DatabaseCreator.java:294)
        ... 135 more
    TID: [] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-10-17 23:36:31,777]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items: {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
    TID: [] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-10-17 23:36:31,781]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Waiting for required OSGi Service: org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskEngineService {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
```

This is  due to a wrog name in the file, GReg try to find postgresql.sql but in that directory you can see just postgres.sql. I just change the name and arraise another error:

```
TID: [-1234] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-10-17 23:38:20,393] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database} -  Error creating HumanTask database {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database}
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing :  CREATE TABLE HT_MESSAGE (MESSAGE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, MESSAGE_DATA CLOB, MESSAGE_HEADER CLOB, MESSAGE_TYPE VARCHAR(255), MESSAGE_NAME VARCHAR(512), TASK_ID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (MESSAGE_ID))
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQLScript(DatabaseCreator.java:323)
    ....
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no existe el tipo «clob»
  Position: 68
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:139)
    ... 136 more
TID: [-1234] [WSO2 Governance Registry] [2012-10-17 23:38:20,437] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer} -  Humantask Database Initialization failed. {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer}
```

I resolve this issue change CLOB by TEXT. but another error appear:

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.HumanTaskServerException: Error creating HumanTask database
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database.setupHumanTaskDatabase(Database.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database.start(Database.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanTaskServer.initDataSource(HumanTaskServer.java:165)
        ... 131 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing :    CREATE TABLE ATTACHMENT ( id BIGINT NOT NULL, ATTACHMENT_CONTENT BYTEA, CONTENT_TYPE VA
RCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CREATED_BY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CREATED_TIME Timestamp NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT current_timestamp, ATTACHMENT_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NUL
L, ATTACHMENT_URL VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) )
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQLScript(DatabaseCreator.java:323)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.db.Database.setupHumanTaskDatabase(Database.java:94)
        ... 133 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de ½WITH DEFAULT+
  Position: 178
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.executeSQL(DatabaseCreator.java:139)
        ... 136 more
[2012-10-18 14:21:44,489]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:

[2012-10-18 14:21:44,493]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Waiting for required OSGi Service: org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.HumanT
askEngineService
```

In this case I removed the WITH expression, and finally i can use GREG 4.5.0 with Postgresql. this could be fixed for he next release?

Comment: "NOT DEFAULT" is incorrect syntax. Just omit the "WITH" : `CREATED_TIME Timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp`. the "WITH" is an Oracle-ism, IIRC. BTW: next release of which?

Comment: next release of GREG :-D

Answer (score 1):

These errors are now corrected in the latest [greg 4.6](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/)

Comment: Please do not include "closings" and signatures in your posts.